# Terrible performance of the GNU Octave `scatter` function compared to MATLAB. Any replacement?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

Why is the performance of `scatter` function so bad in Octave when compared with `plot` function? Also, the MATLAB version of the `scatter` function seems blazing fast compared to its Octave counterpart.

Here are some timings generated on my machine for comparing the efficiency of `scatter` vs `plot`

```
octave:1> 
octave:1> A = rand(1000,2);
octave:2> tic ; plot(A(:,1) , A(:,2));toc;
Elapsed time is 0.0407901 seconds.
octave:3> 
octave:3> 
octave:3> tic ; scatter(A(:,1) , A(:,2));toc;
Elapsed time is 6.16734 seconds.
octave:4>
```

MATLAB requires 0.16229 seconds to perform the same `scatter` function on the same matrix 'A'.

Is there a faster version of `scatter` available for `octave`?

Comment: Just tried, actually `scatter()` works faster for me for your example: `Elapsed time is 0.0116351 seconds. Elapsed time is 0.00910807 seconds.` Probably they fixed that in the last 3.5 years ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your usage of `scatter` but it may be suitable for you:

```
plot(A(:,1) , A(:,2) , `o' )
```

*I don't use Octave but apparently, the string that specifies the format of the line begins with a "grave accent ` " unlike Matlab, according to [this](http://sunsite.univie.ac.at/textbooks/octave/octave_15.html)

Edit: In the examples in the above link, they were using double quotation marks!
so the above would be:

```
plot(A(:,1) , A(:,2) , "o" )
```